# JetBrains Space automation script

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-space-automation, jetbrains-space

I try to solve the following issue:

```
job("Docker | deploy") {
    docker {
        build {
            context = "docker"
            file = "./docker/Dockerfile"
            labels["vendor"] = "mycompany"
            args["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://10.20.30.1:123"
        }

        push("registry.com") {
            versionOne = Params("version-one")
            versionTwo = Params("version-two")
            
            tag = "${'$'}versionOne-${'$'}versionTwo"
        }
    }
}
```

Within the `push` step, the tag should be combined of `versionOne` and `versionTwo` dynamically, but I don't figured it out how to achieve this.

Does someone know how to use variables dynamically in a space automation script?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it below:

```
job("Docker | deploy") {
    env["VERSION_ONE"] = Params("version-one")
    env["VERSION_TWO"] = Params("version-two")

    docker {
        build {
            context = "docker"
            file = "./docker/Dockerfile"
            labels["vendor"] = "mycompany"
            args["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://10.20.30.1:123"
        }

        push("registry.com") {
            tags("${'$'}VERSION_ONE-${'$'}VERSION_TWO")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `docker` DSL is now deprecated. Instead, use the [dockerBuildPush](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/automation-dsl.html#job-host-dockerBuildPush) DSL in a `host` step (instead of a `docker`/`kaniko` step).

Also, for regular project parameters (not secrets), you can use the `{{ project:<param> }}` template syntax instead of going through environment variables:

```kotlin
job("Docker | deploy") {    
    host {
        dockerBuildPush {
            context = "docker"
            tags {
                +"registry.com/image:{{ project:version-one }}-{{ project:version-two }}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```